How to restart AirDrop on a MacBook without restarting macOS?
On my 2015 MacBook Pro (Monterey), I often cannot AirDrop and receive images/files from my iPhone via AirDrop because it isn't broadcasting itself (despite having it set to be discoverable by "Everyone")
There is a lot of junk information on Internet about it.
The quick fix is to reboot macOS and it will work for 24 hours or so and eventually stops for an unknown reasons.
I was wondering if anyone has a better fix than restarting or my below solution?

What I found after digging a fair bit is that you simply need to restart the interface like so:

Open a terminal.
Type the following in the Terminal:
sudo ifconfig awdl0 down
sudo ifconfig awdl0 up


Try again on your iPhone/device. You will see your MacBook for a little while (until it stops again).

Notes:

You could schedule (cron) the above commands to automagically fix itself once a day. I leave that as an exercise for the reader.
If desperate, rebooting is still the simplest fix although (very) annoying.

